# Installing apk Files to device sd-card

Tags: file, installation, apk, sd-card

When a user installs my application I want to install my apk files to the devices SDCARD.

I saw the source code for `PackageManagerService.java`, I can update the install location, but I'm not sure I should be changing that code.

Answer (score 2):

I think should help you:

> [App Install Location (developer.android.com)](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html)

To quote:

> Beginning with API Level 8, you can
>   allow your application to be installed
>   on the external storage (for example,
>   the device's SD card). This is an
>   optional feature you can declare for
>   your application with the
>   `android:installLocation` manifest
>   attribute. If you do not declare this
>   attribute, your application will be
>   installed on the internal storage only
>   and it cannot be moved to the external
>   storage.
>
> To allow the system to install your
>   application on the external storage,
>   modify your manifest file to include
>   the `android:installLocation` attribute
>   in the `<manifest>` element, with a
>   value of either "`preferExternal`" or
>   "`auto`". For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```